# render HTML in Emacs tooltip?

Tags: emacs, tooltip

I would like to display HTML with bold and italic text in Emacs tooltips.  The solution I am trying is like this:

```
(let ((html "regular <b>bold</b> regular <i>italic</i> regular\n")
      (bufname "* render-html-tmp*"))
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create bufname)
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert html)
    (shr-render-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (tooltip-show (buffer-string))))
```

In the `* render-html-tmp*` buffer the bold and italic text show up all right, but in the tooltip all the five words are in plain regular text, without bold or italic.  Changing the value of `x-gtk-use-system-tooltips` has no effect.

At the same time, when I go to the end of the `* render-html-tmp*` buffer and do `(insert (buffer-string))` there, or copy the buffer contents into the kill ring and yank it into a new buffer, the bold and italic attributes do show up correctly in the inserted or yanked text.  So my basic idea should be right, and I am at my wit's end trying to figure out why I am not seeing these attributes in the tooltip.

What's going on, and how to make the bold and italic text show up in the tooltip?

Comment: I think `tooltip-show` overrides whatever face is passed in and add its own `tooltip` face instead.

Comment: @NickD Well, yes! I did have a look at `tooltip.el`, how could I fail to notice this! I only have to define my own version of `tooltip-show` substituting simply `text` for the original `(propertize text 'face 'tooltip)` to make it work just as I want.  (This only works if `x-gtk-use-system-tooltips` is `nil`). Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tooltip-show` overrides the face property of the string that is passed into it and replaces it with its own `tooltip` property:

```
      (x-show-tip (propertize text 'face 'tooltip)
              (selected-frame)
              params
              tooltip-hide-delay
              tooltip-x-offset
              tooltip-y-offset))
      ...
```

As the OP mentions in a comment, defining a modified `tooltip-show` to pass `text` directly to `x-show-tip` instead of doing the `(propertize text ...)` and calling that from his code resolves the problem.

Comment: All tooltips generated by `tooltip-show` will be affected only if I choose to change  `tooltip-show` itself; instead of this, I defined a new function and made the change there.  (I do need the original `tooltip-show` too.)

Comment: Good point - sorry for misstating the case. Edited.